# Connected to a wired network, but internet doesn't work Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, 17.04, wired

Wired network shows connected, but internet doesn't work.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

shows following in terminal :

```
description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 07
   serial: fc:45:96:84:73:b8
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:124 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a3200000-a3200fff memory:a3000000-a3003fff
```

I also tried by disabling secure boot, but it doesn't work too.

on `ifconfig` it shows :

```
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether fc:45:96:84:73:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 104  bytes 12418 (12.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 978  bytes 75957 (75.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 405  bytes 44664 (44.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 405  bytes 44664 (44.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e187:9d1f:f675:9bea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:54:1b:f3:33:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5568  bytes 3045587 (3.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4345  bytes 938706 (938.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note:) I have read most of similar threads/questions here before asking this. None of those works for me

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You do not have ip address on `enp1s0`. Do you have `dhcp` server on wired network?

Comment: If you don't have `dhcp` server on `lan` you must provide `ip`, `nm`, `gw` and `dns` manually for wired connection.

Comment: yes dhcp on wired network.

Comment: Can you give me output from command `nmcli connection show enp1s0`

Comment: It says : Error: enp1s0 - no such connection profile.

Comment: Can you go to `Settings->Network->Your-Network-Connection->Configure->IPV4 Settings` and see `metod` is `manual` or `dhcp` or .. Also you can see interface config with command `sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` If is metod `manual` change it to `dhcp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
What happens when you do the following?

sudo /sbin/modprobe -v -r r8169
sudo /sbin/modprobe -v r8169

If your r8169 comes back into service, then:

Had your machine previously suspended?  That is a well-known weakness
```

in the r8169 kernel object: suspend followed by resume seems to disable the r8169 driver for some reason, going back a few years.
The 2 command lines above work-around that.
I wound up creating a systemd service to automate the work-around for my laptop.

Comment: After trying this it just prints : rmmod r8169 and rmmod mii.. Athought when i connect my pc to a router using lan cable, it works... but when i connect it to port directly, it shows connected to wired network but internet doesn't work